# Apply lyr file to Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, layer-file

I am new to ArcPy, and don't know how to assign different layers to the same `lyr` file. The layers have "pol" in common. Replacement is a single layer, and so must be walked through the entire document.

```
import arcpy.mapping as mapping
... mxd = mapping.MapDocument ("CURRENT")
... df = mapping.ListDataFrames (mxd, "Layers") [0]
... updateLayer = mapping.ListLayers (mxd, "Pol_01_002", df) [0]
... sourceLayer = mapping.Layer (r "g: \ Pol01_001.lyr")
... mapping.UpdateLayer (df, updateLayer, sourceLayer, False)
```

How can I assign a single layer style file to all layers?

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a whole list of your layers and iterate it.
Try this:

```
import arcpy.mapping as mapping
mxd = mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
updateLayers = mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Pol*", df)
sourceLayer = mapping.Layer(r"g:\Pol01_001.lyr")
for uL in updateLayers:
   mapping.UpdateLayer(df, uL, sourceLayer, False)
```